# Do I need a UK transit visa when connecting directly in London Heathrow when travelling with a Dutch RP and Indian Passport?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, transit-visas, netherlands

So, I'm planning my travel from Amsterdam to Hyderabad, India, and I was confused by the various personal accounts and information on the UK government website. I have a Residence Permit from the Netherlands, and I am looking at an itinerary that has a direct connection in London Heathrow, at the same terminal.

My question is, would I be needing a transit visa for both sides of the travel? I see a lot of questions answer on these lines, but nothing recent. So I hope a recent traveller can really help me confirm this. Thank you in advance!